# getting ld to ignore undefined references when making a DLL

Tags: gcc, linker, mingw, ld

I'm trying to get `gcc`'s `ld` to ignore unresolved references when putting together a shared library from a bunch of object files compiled with `-fpic` flag.

I tried a bunch of options so far such as (replaced the long file names of the many object files with a few small ones for brevity):

```
ld --allow-shlib-undefined --unresolved-symbols=ignore-all -shared 1.o 2.o -o lib0.so
ld -G 1.o 2.o -o lib0.so
```

(I've red [somewhere](https://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/libraries.html) that `-G` will allow unresolved references, but had no luck with it.)

Running it though `gcc` (with `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all`) results in fewer unresolved references as it links by default with

```
-lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -liconv -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt
```

but it still complains about not having `-lopengl32` and `-lgdi32`.

Compiling the lib without `-fpic`, stashing all the object files in a `.a` with `ar` and static linking to it while having the exe program link to `-lopengl32` and `-lgdi32` results in working completely fine.

The actual error messages (replaced the long file and function names for brevity):

```
[file].o: In function `[function]': [file].cpp:19: undefined reference to `memcpy'
[file].o: In function `[function]': [file].cpp:26: undefined reference to `memcpy'

[file].o:[file].cpp:(.xdata+0x4c): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
[file].o:[file].cpp:(.xdata+0x74): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
[file].o:[file].cpp:(.rdata$[file]]+0x20):undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
[file].o:[file].cpp:(.rdata$[file]]+0x28): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
```

How can I get `ld` to ignore undefined references (at least from `libopengl32` and `libgdi32` if not `libstdc++` etc too) and let the program thats going to use it link to them?

Comment: When I got the `__gxx_personality_seh0' error in my stuff I compiled with g++ instead of gcc and it went away.  See if that works for you.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thats just one of the many errors there are, basically one for each call to any std function such as `memcpy`, any call to opengl, etc. And the point is that I'm trying to use `ld` not `g++`, the program is compiling just fine to `.o` files, I just want `ld` to make a shared lib out of the `.o` files while not linking to other libs. It works just fine when using `ld` to make a static lib, but when making a shared one, it complains about not linking to stdlib, opengllib, etc. The program that uses the static lib links to std, opengl etc, it should in theory work for shared too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `ld` is not part of gcc. It is part of binutils.

Try to link with `gcc`, or in case of C++ with `g++` instead of `ld`.

Also, on Windows you can't build shared libraries (.dll) or executables (.exe) with unresolved symbols. Part of "DLL hell" is that you must make sure all symbols resolve.

Normally it's a matter of finding the library providing those symbols and adding the required `-l` flags.

However errors like `undefined reference to 'memcpy'` indicate it's not finding stuff in the standard library. So either you're using `ld` that did not come with MinGW or there is a flag like `-nostdlib` present telling the compiler not to look for the standard library.